# How to solve this system of equations for $x^2+y^2+z^2$?

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

For the complex numbers $x,y,z$, the system of equations

> $x^2-yz=i~~~~~
> y^2-zx=i~~~~~
> z^2-xy=i$

It is not easy for me to get $x^2+y^2+z^2$ from the above. I *don't* need the values of $x,y,z$

I'm stuck in what to do at first. Any advice would be helpful.

My attempt : we can get $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx=3i$, 
so $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=6i$
I actually don't know whether this is a right way to solve the above.

Comment: Luke, why did you delete [the first version of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341392/how-to-solve-this-system-of-equations-for-x2y2z2)? Reasking the same question is against the site norms. You should have edited that question instead. Adding an explanation of your attempt might have gotten it reopened in due course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting the equations in pairs we get

$$(x-y)(x+y+z) = 0$$
$$(x-z)(x+y+z) = 0$$
$$(y-z)(x+y+z) = 0$$

If $x+y+z \not = 0$ then $x=y=z$, but then $x^2-yz = 0 \not = i$ so we must have $x+y+z = 0$.

Next we can use the identity

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = (x+y+z)^2 - 2(xy+yz+xz)$$

togeather with the equation system to arrive at

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2 i + \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{3} = 2i$$

Answer (score 0):

<sup>$\sqrt i$ denotes $e^{i\pi/4}$</sup>
$$(x^2-yz)-(z^2-xy)=i-i\\\implies(x-z)(x+z)-y(x+z)=0\\\implies(x+z)(x-y-z)=0$$

## Case I: $x+z=0\implies z=-x$

$$x^2-xy=i,y^2+x^2=i\implies x^2-xy=x^2+y^2\implies y(x+y)=0$$

## Case Ia: $x+y=0\implies y=-x$

$$2x^2=i\implies x=\sqrt\frac i2,y=z=-\sqrt\frac i2$$

## Case Ib: $y=0$

$$x=\sqrt i,y=0,z=-\sqrt i$$

## Case II: $x=y+z$

<sup>continue....</sup>

Comment: And one also need to remember to check that the solutions found are true solutions. For example $x=\sqrt{i/2},y=z=-\sqrt{i/2}$ is not a true solution since $x^2 - yz = 0$.